# Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel Open and Sheet error

Tags: c#, excel

I have a problem that i don't get.
Let me explain first how my soft works.

I've develop 3 different software looping every minute, two of them are openning the same excel file but not at the same time, but one of those is crashing sometimes, it can be after 8 hour, after 2 days or after 1 hour. What a mess..

And it can be on *xlWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(path);* or *xlWorksheet = xlWorkbook.Sheets{1};*

Here's the part giving me an error :

```
    public Excel.Application xlApp = new Excel.Application();
    public Excel.Workbook xlWorkbook;
    public Excel._Worksheet xlWorksheet;
    public Excel.Range xlRange;

    public void CsvParcoursVisuCrea(string flux, double delay, string hour, string name, string date, int index)
    {
        DateTime dateconvert = DateTime.Parse(date);
        string path = domain + @"TCD_ParcoursVisu.xlsx";
        if (!path.IsFileOpen())
        {
            if (index == 0)
                xlWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(path);

            if (xlWorkbook == null)
            {
                if (index == 0)
                    LogWriteToFile("Error in workbook, impossible to open", "ALERT : WorkBook error");
            }
            else
            {
                if (index == 0)
                    LogWriteToFile("TCD_ParcoursVisu.xlsx is now open", "Process : Creation TCD parcours");

                xlWorksheet = xlWorkbook.Sheets[1];
                xlRange = xlWorksheet.UsedRange;

                int rowCount = xlRange.Rows.Count;
                int colCount = xlRange.Columns.Count;

                if (rowCount <= 1)
                {
                    xlWorksheet.Cells[rowCount, 1] = "Flux";
                    xlWorksheet.Cells[rowCount, 2] = "Nom Parcours";
                    xlWorksheet.Cells[rowCount, 3] = "Date";
                    xlWorksheet.Cells[rowCount, 4] = "Heure";
                    xlWorksheet.Cells[rowCount, 5] = "Minute";



                }
                xlWorksheet.Cells[rowCount + 1, 1] = flux;
                xlWorksheet.Cells[rowCount + 1, 2] = name;
                xlWorksheet.Cells[rowCount + 1, 3] = dateconvert;
                xlWorksheet.Cells[rowCount + 1, 4] = hour;
                xlWorksheet.Cells[rowCount + 1, 5] = delay / 60;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            LogWriteToFile("Being used by another process", "Process : Parcours visu crea");
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Here's a screenshot of my last log line before crash

[image: Here's a screenshot of my last log line before crash]

I've launched it at 10AM.

Here's the method calling CsvParcoursVisuCrea in my soft crashing :

```
    private void AllCsvCreation()
    {
        SumParcours();
        int[] tabMemorySum = IndexSum();

        for (int i = 0; i < parcObj.Date.Length; i++)
        {
                if (parcObj.Date[i] != null)
                {
                    CsvCreation(parcObj.Date[tabMemoryIndex[i]], parcObj.Hour[tabMemoryIndex[i]], parcObj.Exploitant, parcObj.Name[tabMemoryIndex[i]], tabMemorydelay[tabMemorySum[i] - 1].ToString(), parcObj.Fiability[tabMemoryIndex[i]].ToString(), parcObj.StrnmeDelayXystaXyendScore[tabMemoryIndex[i]], i);
                    CsvParcoursVisuCrea(parcObj.Exploitant, tabMemorydelay[tabMemorySum[i] - 1], parcObj.Hour[tabMemoryIndex[i]], parcObj.Name[tabMemoryIndex[i]], parcObj.Date[tabMemoryIndex[i]], i);
                }
        }

        //Cleanup
        GC.Collect();
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
        //Close and release
        xlApp.DisplayAlerts = false;
        xlWorkbook.Save();
        xlWorkbook.Close();
        xlApp.DisplayAlerts = true;
    }
```

CsvCreation and CsvParcoursVisuCrea aren't opening the same Csv, CsvCreation never crashed, i fill CsvCreation with AppendLine().

Hope its clear, its very long i'm sorry.

Comment: *Here's the part giving me an error* And what does error say? Try to open workbook in read-only mode:`xlApp.Workbooks.Open("FILE_PATH", ReadOnly: true);`

Comment: But i edit the workbook, why would I open it in read-only ?
The error say COM error something like that

Comment: *something like that* Could you be more specific? We're not obliged to guess...

Comment: I would if i could.
I'll edit when the error appear

Comment: Meanwhile, I'd like to say that you have some over-complicated logic with opening workbook. As I guess, you just need to check whether workbook is opened. Then what role does `index` play?

Comment: index role is to open the workbook on the first iteration, otherwise he would be open several times, because there's multiple call on CsvParcoursVisuCrea

Comment: Let me explain how my open works, every minute on 1 software, there's a open going and then a close to let the other software open and close to his turn etc etc
I can't just call 1 open on both software it will crash right ?

ERROR : HRESULT : 0x800AC472

Answer (score 0):

Got it, 
All i had is to handle the exception that the file is currently locked, seems like after some research, the Interop sometimes lock which is why my soft crash.